# autofac: IEnumerable<Lazy<IFoo, IFooMetaData>> --> Lazy.Value(with runtime param)?

Tags: autofac

Using Autofac, I have multiple IFoo components that take a run-time parameter in the constructor.  I'm using some Metadata from the types along with the run-time parameter to construct and manage running instances.

```
interface IFoo
{
    int RunTimeId { get; }
}

[FooMeta("ShaqFoo")]
class Foo1 : IFoo
{
    public Foo1 (int runtTimeId)
    {
        ...

}

[FooMeta("KungFoo")]
class Foo2 : IFoo
{
    public Foo2 (int runtTimeId)
    {
       ...
}
```

Module/Registration something like:

```
    builder.Register<Func<int, Foo1>>(c => 
        { 
            var cc = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>(); 
            return id => cc.Resolve<Foo1>(TypedParameter.From<int>(id)); 
        })
        .As<Func<int, IFoo>>()
        .WithMetadata<IFooMetaData>(m => m.For(sm => sm.FooType, typeof(Foo1)));

    builder.Register<Func<int, Foo2>>(c => 
        { 
            var cc = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>(); 
            return id => cc.Resolve<Foo2>(TypedParameter.From<int>(id)); 
        })
        .As<Func<int, IFoo>>()
        .WithMetadata<IFooMetaData>(m => m.For(sm => sm.FooType, typeof(Foo2)));
```

And a component that creates new Foos with the run-time parameters and metadata.  I need to be create ALL IFoos for a given run-time parameter, and need to check for existing instances (essentially using Metadata + RunTimeId as a key) before creating.

```
public class FooActivator
{
    public FooActivator(IEnumerable<Lazy<Func<int, IFoo>, IFooMetaData>> fooFactories)
    {
        m_FooFactories = fooFactories;
    }

    private void HandleNewRunTimeIdEvent(int id)
    {
        CreateFoosForNewId(id);
    }

    private void CreateFoosForNewId(int id)
    {
        foreach (var fooFactory in m_FooFactories)
        {
            if (!FooWithThisMetadataAndIdExists(fooFactory.Metadata.FooType, id))
            {
                var newFoo = fooFactory.Value(id);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Obviously, I can enumerate all of the IFoos and check metadata using the Lazy Enumeration, but can't pass in the run-time parameter to Lazy.Value.  Seems like I need to pass in an Enumerable of Func<>s somehow, but can't figure out how to attach the metadata.  Or maybe I need an entirely different approach?

Just getting my head wrapped around autofac, and hoping there's a clean way to accomplish this.  I could settle for just using the concrete Foo type (instead of metadata) if there's a simple way to enumerate all of them (without creating them), and use the type + run-time Id as my key instead.

Answer (score 0):

Updated the code with a working solution.  Figured out how to register Factories properly with metadata.  Seems to work.